# What's the safest way to remove an admin from an existing open zepplin ERC20 token?

Tags: solidity, openzeppelin

Lets say you have this erc20 token already made, what's the safest way to no longer allow the mint and burn functions to work? Is there a better solution than creating a smart contract, updating the token admin to that contract, then using the selfdestruct() function to render that contract useless?

Here's code:

```
import '@openzeppelin/contracts@4.4.2/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol';

contract Token is ERC20 {
  address public admin;

  constructor(string memory name, string memory symbol) ERC20(name, symbol) {
    admin = msg.sender;
  }

  function updateAdmin(address updateadmin) external {
    require(msg.sender == admin, 'only admin');
    admin = updateadmin;
  }

  function mint(address to, uint amount) external {
    require(msg.sender == admin, 'fail, admin only');
    _mint(to, amount);
  }

  function burn(address owner, uint amount) external {
    require(msg.sender == admin, 'fail, admin only');
    _burn(owner, amount);
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're sure you want to revoke admin privileges, you can call `updateAdmin()` with the zero address, essentially burning that role forever. As you can see on [Etherscan](https://etherscan.io/address/0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000), the zero address was often used as a "burn" address.

Keep in mind this is unrecoverable if you do it!

Comment: Thanks! Using "burn" address, there's no implications on any of the functions in ERC20.sol? There are many comments of variables requiring 'cannot be the zero address'. I assume no issue, even if owner was one of those requires, that address still exists.

Comment: Which opens another thought. If the owner address is still valid after burn, are there any functions the owner address could utilize to manipulate the token (ie: mint more supply and sell it to the market for all the eth in the contract)?